# How to check the quality of clustering results if there is no labels?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, hierarchical-clustering, model-evaluation

How can we check the quality of clustering of no-labeled data?

I learnt from class that there are some ways to achieve this . One is to 
"measure intra-cluster cohesion (how near the data points within a
cluster) and and inter-cluster separation (how far apart different
clusters are from one another)".

Is there any ways to determine how cohesion this dataset are needed?

Or do we have other quantitative methods to check the clustering quality?

Comment: I think if you search the site you will find a duplicate or several potential duplicates.